# how to programmaticaly increase the width of a custom uiview and all its subviews in uiviewcontroller by clicking on a button

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a custom UIview
I need to increase its width and also the width of its subviews like webviews and another label etc. dynamically.

I have used 
`_view.setframe - xframe;`// this increases the width but the content stays where it is
_view setneedsdisplay or needslayout are not working.
Do I use the autoresizing mask before adding the view in controller? and how?

Can someone please tell me how to go about doing this.

Thanks

Comment: You need to set autoResizesSubviews on the parent to YES, then set the autoresizingmask for each subview. Here is the documentation for autoresizingmask https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW5

Comment: @mkral You should make that an answer.

Comment: @JesseRusak , sorry was trying to type it quick. I've added apple's picture in my answer post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your inputs
but i worked by recalling
[self layoutSubviews];//and changing the widths

Answer (score 2):

You need to set autoResizesSubviews on the parent to YES, then set the autoresizingmask for each subview. Here is the documentation for autoresizingmask

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW5

This image from apple should help you understand:
[image]

Comment: so if i do this on parentview  _view.setframe = 400; will it resize subviews?

Comment: yes, as long as you set up the subviews to have flexible margins/heights/widths depending on what you want to do.

Comment: do i reload the viewcontroller after it? I not using a xib file here could you post an example?